# Is there a way to check for a set of four things in a list and then remove them all in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write code to simulate something like placing a set of four cards down from the player’s. I want to be able to check for a set of four identical cards in a list and then remove them all from the list and make an external “point” value increase by one. Essentially like playing down a set in a game like go fish.

I can only figure out how to do it with 2 cards in the set. And in my deck there are no suits since the game is go fish and the suits dont matter for it. So i only need to figure it out for the rank of the cards

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Count how many of each card there are then remove any with a count of four.  Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.